# Improve my jquery selector / wordpress php query

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, selector

Hi I'd like to make my jquery selector more efficient. Can anybody help me out? I presume I can somehow only target the parent / child.

I would also like to improve my query in the wordpress php code.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

php:

```
<figure class="about-us">
    <div class="overlay">
        <h1><?php echo get_the_title(13); ?></h1>
        <h2><?php global $wp_query; $postid = 13; 
            echo get_post_meta($postid, 'Subheading', true); ?></h2>
    </div>
    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/img/Prelude-To-A-Number-Rehearsal-190114.jpg" alt="Prelude To A Number rehearsals">
    <figcaption><p><?php global $wp_query; $postid = 13; 
            echo get_post_meta($postid, 'Description', true); ?></p>    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    if ($(".nav ul").css("text-align") == "center" ){
        $(".overlay h1").hide();
        $(".overlay h2").hide();
        $("figcaption").hide(); 
        $(".current-projects" ).hover(function(){
            $('.current-projects .overlay h1').fadeToggle();
            $('.current-projects .overlay h2').fadeToggle();
            $('.current-projects figcaption').slideToggle();
        })
        $(".past-projects" ).hover(function(){
            $('.past-projects .overlay h1').fadeToggle();
            $('.past-projects .overlay h2').fadeToggle();
            $('.past-projects figcaption').slideToggle();
        })
        $(".about-us" ).hover(function(){
            $('.about-us .overlay h1').fadeToggle();
            $('.about-us .overlay h2').fadeToggle();
            $('.about-us figcaption').slideToggle();
        })
        $(".pen-chant" ).hover(function(){
            $('.pen-chant .overlay h1').fadeToggle();
            $('.pen-chant .overlay h2').fadeToggle();
            $('.pen-chant figcaption').slideToggle();
        })
        $(".media" ).hover(function(){
            $('.media .overlay h1').fadeToggle();
            $('.media .overlay h2').fadeToggle();
            $('.media figcaption').slideToggle();
        })
        $(".gigs" ).hover(function(){
            $('.gigs .overlay h1').fadeToggle();
            $('.gigs .overlay h2').fadeToggle();
            $('.gigs figcaption').slideToggle();
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Please only post focussed and specific questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Belongs on wordpress.stackexchange.com site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selector1,selector2` (comma separated) for handling the event & below is the example for handling for 2 classes. Just add more commas for your case.

```
$(".current-projects, .past-projects" ).hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.overlay').find('h1').fadeToggle();
    $(this).find('.overlay').find('h2').fadeToggle();
    $(this).find('figcaption').slideToggle();
})
```

You can also make it simpler by adding a common class to each of the divs & avoid comma separation. for instance, lets say the class is `commonClass`

```
$(".commonClass" ).hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.overlay').find('h1').fadeToggle();
    $(this).find('.overlay').find('h2').fadeToggle();
    $(this).find('figcaption').slideToggle();
})
```

Comment: Depends on the (I think rather safe) assumption that there's only one `.current-projects`, etc. element, but I was going to post the same thing.

Comment: You should cache `$(this)` in a local variable, and also cache `$(this).find('.overlay')`. There is no reason to call these methods thrice & twice, respectively.

Comment: Thank you Krishna, your second option is the one I used, simply targeting the html element 'figure'. I did not know about the .find() jquery method for searching through descendants. Very helpful!